# How to start the standard Stopwatch activity in Android (particularly Andorid Wear) programmatically?

Tags: android

I am working on a launcher application for Android Wear, and would like to include icons for the default actions such as "Set Alarm", "Set Timer", "Show Alarms" or the Stopwatch.

I found the way to start alarm clock related activities using the following intents:

- AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER  or "android.intent.action.SET_TIMER"
- AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM or "android.intent.action.SHOW_ALARMS"
- AlarmClock.ACTION_SHOW_ALARMS or "android.intent.action.SET_ALARM"

I can start them by:

```
Intent i= new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_TIMER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
context.startActivity(i);
```

If started without any extras, they simply bring up the corresponding UI. Perfect! 
**Except,** I can't find the corresponding action for the **Stopwatch**. Do you know the intent? Where should I look?

Comment: I found out the name of the package: "com.google.android.deskclock" and there is a service called "com.android.deskclock.stopwatch.StopwatchService", but I can see no activity that I could start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @promanowicz 's answer like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.wearable.action.STOPWATCH" );
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone. At the moment there is intent action 'com.google.android.wearable.action.STOPWATCH' which you can use.

[According to this training- Adding Voice Capabilities](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html)

Answer (score -1):

The starting and stopping Stopwatch is not exposed via public API or intent